# Function logs in console, but not returning any value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a program in javascript that requires me to get the source data of an image, convert it to base64, and then output it as a relevant html tag. The problem is, the function works when I attempt to log it in console, but it refuses to work when I return it instead.

Any idea on what's going on?

**Not Working**

*undefined*

```js
function imageUploaded()
{
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]')['files'][0];
  
    var reader = new FileReader();
      
    reader.onload = function ()
    {
        base64String = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.+,/, "");
  
        imageBase64Stringsep = base64String;
        return base64String; 
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

**Working**

*base64 encoded string*

```js
function imageUploaded()
{
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]')['files'][0];
  
    var reader = new FileReader();
      
    reader.onload = function ()
    {
        base64String = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.+,/, "");
  
        imageBase64Stringsep = base64String;
        console.log(base64String); 
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

**Update**

I've solved one problem but stumbled onto another!

Returning the reader object and logging it into the console shows that the object contains the relevant values under 'result', however whenever I try to log the result itself by doing `console.log(myVar.result)`, I'm getting `null` as an output. This doesn't seem right to me, because the object has the data when you log it normally! What's happening?

`console.log(myVar)`
[image]

Comment: This could be an asynchronous call?

Comment: You're trying to return a value in the inner callback. That won't do you any good.

Comment: I've realised that, however there is another issue that has arisen.